# How to format currency like kendo ui 's template using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, formatting, currency, euro

I want to get this format In USD : 1.123.362,32 and this format  in euro :1,122,363.33
I used AngularJS Filter "currency" who Format a number to a currency format but without separtors like "," "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use a Filter

[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) is a link to the docs where you can see an example.

You need to use the currency filter to get the desired effect. It should look like this

**HTML**

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

**JS**

```
$filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)
```

To do this with the correct , or . you need to have the correct currency format selected.

## Math.round()

inside your controller when you are setting the scope make sure you do Math.round() so the number you return is always whole.

## Example

```
Math.round(2.5);
```

## Alternatively

If the currency filter does not meet your requirements you can always use the number format that Angular provides, Doc are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

**HTML**

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

**JS**

```
$filter('number')(number, fractionSize)
```

## If All Else Fails

Create your own custom filter [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) is a tutorial on how to build your own custom filter in angular, since your requirements are a little strange you should consider building your own filter to match them. This way you can set your , or . and anything that precedes or follows your number.

Its definitely more difficult than using the built in functionality but since you cant get it to match up with either of the methods above I would take this route.

Comment: do that in your controller before sending it to the front. like `Math.round(2.5);`

Comment: I want to get this format  without fractionSize .
exemple of kendo ui template currency :
template: "#= kendo.toString(2363633, 'c', 'fr-FR')#" ,
the result : 2 363 633,00 € 
template: "#= kendo.toString(2363633, 'c', 'en-CA')#" ,
the result :
$ 2,363,633.00  
Ususally €  after the variable and $ before variable

Answer (score 0):

currency angularjs's filter does not deal comma in usd and point in euro.... I used kendo ui like the filter in grid,it deal all event :
kendo.toString(236, 'c', fr-FR);
hope we find a complete solution with angularjs.